# Map to endpoint based on header parameter in AWS API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

Would like to proxy request through Amazon API gateway. While doing so, I would like to select endpoint based on the value of header parameter.

For e.g. if header variable **prod** is true, request has to be proxied to `https://prod.backend.com`, else, it has to be proxied to `https://sandbox.backend.com`.

Looked into [staging variables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/stage-variables.html) but not clear, how this can be used. Appreciate any suggestion on how this can be achieved.

Comment: Have you tried replacing with integration variable, {method.request.header.headername} ?

Comment: why don't you have 2 different apis and just have each one with one sub domain ?

Comment: @dege Unfortunately, I can't change the API on client.

Comment: @user10629334  sure, but if you use custom domains of the api gateway you can point into difference stages of the APIGW instance
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-custom-domains.html

Comment: @Kannaiyan Do you mean to say create a URL path mapping from variable? Also, if variable is not defined in the header, how do we map it?

Comment: It is just header itself. Any value you pass it in the header will be passed in that variable automatically.